# Unable to interpret matplotlib plotting

Tags: matplotlib

I got the following code from one of the training classes.

```
from sklearn.datasets import make_moons

X, y = make_moons(n_samples=1000, noise=0.1, random_state=0)
plt.plot(X[y==0, 0], X[y==0, 1], 'ob', alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(X[y==1, 0], X[y==1, 1], 'xr', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(['0', '1'])
```

I am unable to understand the following.

1. X,y will be assigned 1000 data points? how we will differenciate values between X and y
2. plt.plot(X[y==0, 0], X[y==0, 1] & plt.plot(X[y==1, 0], X[y==1, 1] what we are trying here? I did not understand X[y==0, 0], X[y==0, 1] and X[y==1, 0], X[y==1, 1].

can someone please help me to comprehend the above code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say these are very basic questions and you might need to brush up on your python knowledge before launching on anything more advanced.

- [Looking at the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_moons.html,), `make_moons` returns a tuple (X,y) which is *unpacked* into the variables X and y. It is the same logic that allows you to write:

  a,b = 1,2

which yields 2 variables `a` and `b` equal to `1` and `2` respectively.

- `X` is a matrix of dimensions `(1000,2)` the syntax `X[:,0]` gets you the first column, and `X[:,1]` the second column. In addition, the code is selecting only the rows where, for instance, `y==0`. `y` is a vector of shape `(1000,)`, `y==0` returns a vector of shape `(1000,)` where each element is either `True` or `False` depending on whether the element is equal 0 or not. Therefore `X[y==0, 0]` returns only the first column of `X` and the rows where `y` is equal 0. Read more about array *indexing* at https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: Thanks Asahi. It makes sense now. I got confused with the syntax, but thanks for your help.